# Activity dropped because this channel is not enabled for this bot

Tags: botframework

I tried to chat with my bot via Teams. It worked at the beginning. After a couple of tries, playing around with the code and getting to know it.
The bot didn't respond in Teams anymore.
I tested with the Bot Framework Emulator, localhost and with ngrok remote on my WebApi. It worked fine. Then I tested the WebClient as a Bot Channel, there it worked as well.
At first I got the Error Message "Activity dropped because this channel is not enabled for this bot", now I don't get any errors anymore but the bot is still not responding.

Did anybody experienced this kind of issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a known bug that when the Skype channel is disabled, Teams also stops responding.  If you've disabled Skype try re-enabling it as a temporary work around until a fix is published.

Comment: I think this was the issue why the error occured. I've added Skype back, because I removed it as you mentioned. Now it still doesn't work, I tried to remove Teams but I cannot edit it: Sad bot is sad.